# Writing Unittest which takes 2 list

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am a new Junit Learner I would like to test my code according to 2 list class. However I never saw any example of that.

My real code is below :

```
public static List<JourneyType> applyFilter(List<JourneyType> journeyList, List<AvailabilityFilterOptionType> filterOptions)
{
    List<JourneyType> filteredJourneyList = new ArrayList<>();

    filteredJourneyList = applyStopFilters(journeyList, filterOptions);
    filteredJourneyList = applyCarrierFilters(filteredJourneyList, filterOptions);
    filteredJourneyList = applyRbdFilters(filteredJourneyList, filterOptions);
    filteredJourneyList = applyDurationFilter(filteredJourneyList, filterOptions);
    return filteredJourneyList;
}
```

and my test scenario :

```
@Test
public void testApplyFilter() 
{
    fail("Not yet implemented");
}
```

Thank you in advanced

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is pretty simple.

```
@Test
public void testApplyFilter() 
{
    assertThat(someObject.applyFilter(journies, filters), is(expectedOutcome));
}
```

In other words: you know what this method is supposed to do. ( Well, such knowledge is the prerequisite for testing stuff. When you don't know what your code is doing, there is no point in verifying its correctness via testing...)

As in: given some known input data, you should be able put down an **expectation** about output coming back. And that is what you check for.

Of course, the tricky part *could* be to correctly identify dependencies, and mock them where needed.

But ideally, your test should just be that: testing the public contract of your method under test. Something goes in, and you check that the output coming back meets your expectations. Ideally, you have to mock *nothing* for such tests, because you do not at all rely on testing implementation details. You only test the public contract "given this input, this is the expected output".

( where: `assertThat()` is just a different type of assert, and `is()` is a [hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/) matcher. There are many other hamcrest matchers, such as `containsInAnyOrder()` (that one is really neat if you don't care about the order of elements returned, but one has to understand that is used slightly different, it would need `containsInAnyOrder(expectedOutcomeList.toArray())` methinks )

Comment: thank you so much sir,kindly asking you what I can put inside of someobject for giving example and expectedOutcome

Comment: It is your code. From all the people looking at this method under test, *you* are the only one who (should!) know the contract of this method. In order to test it, one has to understand what the method does. We don't know that. You do! If you don't know what your code is supposed to do, sorry, we can't help with that. That is the whole point of my answer!